# Refreshing page after making changes doesn't render in web browser

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, node.js, npm

I'm learning angular and have cloned the repository here. I've installed the dependcies through npm and have the web server running. I can load the page up at localhost:4000.

If I make a change to the index.html (a simple text change), I can see the results when refreshing my browser. But, if I make a change to an html page that's loaded as an angular directive, the changes don't appear in my browser (Chrome, FIrefox). I tried F5, Ctrl+F5, Shift+F5, etc. Even restarting the web server doesn't do anything.

Is there something I need to set up in the angular code so that refreshes work properly?

https://github.com/codeschool/WatchUsBuild-ReadingListAppWithAngularJS

Note, this is Angular 1x proj.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### [Should I blame caching](http://shouldiblamecaching.com/)

It's cached in your browser. Simply have your dev tools open and under networking tab mark disable cache.

> Note:- this will work only if dev tools are open not otherwise.

I can recommend live-server which detect the changes and update make an reload in browser.

One more thing Angular it self use template cache by default so that can also cause the problem and in that case you need to rebuild your app on changes.

[read about template cache](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$templateCache)

Comment: OK, what dev tools do you speak of?

Comment: dev tools  in browser. f12 to open it

Comment: Disabling the cache under the Network tab on the browser dev tools works. Thanks for the other info as well.

Answer (score 0):

Yes that happens with angular because the browsers usually cache the webpages and when you make changes in html and then refresh, the browser loads the cached pages instead. It doesn't happen every time but most of the time. So try clearing the cache of the browser and then load the page. It should work correctly.

Angular 2 and ember has some mechanism called watches that look for changes you make in the files, and whenever it detects a change, it re compiles all files and load a fresh copy for you. But in Angular 1 I don't think there is such a mechanism and I faced this problem my self a lot. And this is the solution I have come across so far. Hope someone else has a better solution.